# Do Keith David's side quests just take you to the already marked activites on the map?

Tags: saints-row-iv

Lately, Keith David and I have been tearing around Fake Steelport doing crimes and punching aliens in the nards, and it's been great.  But I've noticed that all of his missions are just strung-together map activites, like "Jump on these platforms" and "Climb up this tower".

**Do Keith David's side quests just take you to the already marked activites on the map?**

And if so, **will I get the indicated sidequest rewards by doing the activities on my own, without the quest active?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially all the non-loyalty side missions from all the characters will consist of nothing but completing the activities and targets already marked on the map. Kinzie's will always entirely consist of Store Hacking, whereas the other characters' side missions will be more varied. Ultimately, completing every side mission will require you to complete basically everything on the map, though you will only need to get bronze on the activities.

As to your second question, **no**, you cannot get the sidequest's rewards just for doing the activities/targets on your own without the mission. You **can** however do the activities/targets long before taking on the mission, and complete the mission in basically no time at all once you take it. At most, you'll need to head into the simulation, walk around a bit while people talk, then return to the ship to get the reward. You can even get partial credit; if a side mission has five activities in it, and you've done three before taking on the quest, then three objectives will already be complete, and you'll only need to do the other two.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.** The objectives on the map are used very frequently for the side quests given to you by the vice president (and other people later). In fact, the side activities make up pretty much all of these side quests. If you do them on your own, they still count as done when you start the appropriate quest that requires it.